# Globally available object in django for frequent acess

Tags: python, django, caching

I'm relatively new to Django & learning it bit-by-bit. 
I've subscribed to a service, which uses a DLL to provide the data I need. 

To get the required data from the service, I have to make a few initializations; the code for which takes around 2-3 seconds (Requires dispatching a DLL, and then making an init call as follows:)

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
#pythoncom.CoInitialize()
zk = Dispatch("easyconnect.serverside")
print(zk.cmdInit(MY_ID, MY_PASS, SERVER_IP))
```

I need the zk object be available globally, to all the other modules so that I do not have to perform init ambiguously and speed up the data access process.
 

I tried **Django's caching framework**, which helps caching the entire site, or web pages, but I think it's not what I want. Also, putting zk into the cache returns me an error which states that it cannot be put into the cache.

What are some alternatives to address my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define your client globally and access in other modules, but the problem is this client will initialized as soon as the app is loaded but we do not want this extra connection time during app loading we want to start a client only when we need it and only once hence you need [django.utils.functional.LazyObject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/utils/functional/) (A wrapper for another class that can be used to delay instantiation of the wrapped class)

**clients.py** (lets create a lazy client)

```
from django.utils.functional import LazyObject
from django.conf import settings

from win32com.client import Dispatch


class EasyConnect:
    def __init__(self):
        self.easy_connect = Dispatch('easyconnect.serverside')
        self.easy_connect.cmdInit(
            settings.EASSYCONNECT_ID,
            settings.EASSYCONNECT_PASS,
            settings.EASSYCONNECT_IP
        )


class EasyConnectClient(LazyObject):
    def _setup(self):
        self._wrapped = EasyConnect()

client = EasyConnectClient()
```

Now to access this client from other modules:

```
from clients import client
client.easy_connect.make_request()  # make_request is just dummy method, use actual method
```

Comment: Would it be simpler to load the `Dispatch` object in `_setup`?

Comment: @JF thats what i did earlier, but the problem is dispatch object defines `initCmd` which needs to be lazy the `LazyObject` works on default `__init__` (Certainly above code can be improved but at the moment that's what i have only in my mind)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your initialisation  code at the top level of a module - making your zk object  a module global - then import it from where you need it. The initialisation  code will only be executed  once per process at the very first import. If you want to make sure this code is executed before  any request put it in one of your models modules  (or import it from one of your models)

Example (Q&D):

```
# myapp/client.py
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from django.conf import settings

def init():
    #pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    zk = Dispatch("easyconnect.serverside")
    zk.cmdInit(settings.MY_ID, settings.MY_PASS, settings.SERVER_IP)
    return zk

connection = init()
```

And then

```
# myapp/models.py    
# ...
from myapp import client

# ...
def do_something(*args, **kw):
    return client.connection.some_method(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: can you please explain 'putting code at the top level of a module'? I tried make a test module in which i wrote an init() doing my initialization of zk & imported that module in the module which has to access data frequently, calling init in one request, and then in  another request I tried to access data from zk, which returned me the declared None type, not giving me the previously initialized zk reference.